# How to allocate std array memory from huge pages

Tags: c++, linux, performance

My C++ application contains an `std::array`.

I have Linux configured to use Huge Pages. It is set to 'madvise', rather than 'always' so I need my application to request huge pages.

How can I instruct `std::array` to use memory from huge pages?

Comment: Not easily, you'd be better off using `std::vector`, an array can only use local memory, so will be stored directly in whatever contains it

Comment: What? The question is non sensical. `std::array` allocates on the stack or whereever it is constructed at - but it is never its responsibility. It is not a `std::vector` that allocates memory on the heap.

Comment: Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with a custom allocator that allocates memory in your huge page. [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a fixed size type with automatic storage only and its allocation can not be customized

Comment: Since this question doesn't make any sense, (`std::array` doesn't allocate anything) your best bet would be to explain the problem you are actually trying to solve, (instead of the technique you think will solve it). That will enable people to give you the best advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with `std::array`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array says:

> The struct combines the performance and accessibility of a C-style array with the benefits of a standard container, such as knowing its own size, supporting assignment, random access iterators, etc.

Part of the "performance of a C-style array" would be the ability to have all the data in-line in your struct or class, or on the stack. That precludes the possibility of letting `std::array` have a pointer to its data, meaning that you can't make it use any external allocation (e.g. hugepages).

Alternatives off the top of my head:

- Use another data structure that can wrap your preallocated hugepage pointer (maybe a `std::span` with a static extent?)
- Use another data structure that can use a custom allocator (e.g. `std::vector`)
- Create the data structure containing your `std::array` in hugepage memory, so that its in-struct `std::array` will also be in hugepage memory

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` does not allocate or manage memory in any way (it's basically a C array in a struct). If you want it to be allocated in a certain way, you should do that yourself, and then construct the array in the memory you've already allocated.